# Object Type not convertable in string Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, object

I have a column with text which is stored as a object tpye in a pandas dataframe.
The following two codes to not work. The required column is still object type.

```
TD_Eco_Comb_c['CountryPair'] = TD_Eco_Comb_c['CountryPair'].astype('|S')
TD_Eco_Comb_c['CountryPair'] = TD_Eco_Comb_c['CountryPair'].astype('str')
```

Any advice?

Comment: With the imminent release of 1.0, there will be a dedicated str type: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#dedicated-string-data-type

Answer (score 1):

A string is always going to have `dtype == 'object'` in a dataframe.

This comes from numpy, which uses purely numerical dtypes. Everything that isn't numerical is classified as an 'object'. Your data is already in the format you need it to be in.

Comment: Thank you. How is it possible to show this than in a heatmap or visualize it. The problem is I can not plot it.

Comment: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: I don't think I understand your questions, but they seem like they're better suited for an entirely new question rather than trying to expand on this one, which was "why can't I convert this to a string?"